# How can I add timer in CameraX preview after pressing the Start video recording button?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camerax

My requirement is that I have to built a video recording app using Android JAVA in which user will save his 30 seconds of video which will be sent to the another server. User will use the video recording only for once.

> I just want user to see the timer starting from 0 to 30 seconds so just after when he presses the Start Recording button.

How can I do so? Please help me. Sharing my code below.

```
public class VideoKycActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer, View.OnClickListener {
        private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

    PreviewView previewView;
    private VideoCapture videoCapture;
    private Button bRecord;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
        bRecord = findViewById(R.id.bRecord);
        bRecord.setText("start recording"); // Set the initial text of the button
        
        bRecord.setOnClickListener(this);

        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                startCameraX(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, getExecutor());

    }

    Executor getExecutor() {
        return ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private void startCameraX(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());


        // Video capture use case
        videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
                .setVideoFrameRate(30)
                .build();

        // Image analysis use case
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(getExecutor(), this);

        //bind to lifecycle:
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture);

    }

    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
        // image processing here for the current frame
        Log.d("TAG", "analyze: got the frame at: " + image.getImageInfo().getTimestamp());
        image.close();
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.bRecord:
                if (bRecord.getText() == "start recording"){
                    bRecord.setText("stop recording");
                    recordVideo();
                } else {
                    bRecord.setText("start recording");
                    videoCapture.stopRecording();
                }
                break;

        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private void recordVideo() {
        if (videoCapture != null) {

            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, timestamp);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");

            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                videoCapture.startRecording(
                        new VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                                getContentResolver(),
                                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                contentValues
                        ).build(),
                        getExecutor(),
                        new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull VideoCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                                Toast.makeText(VideoKycActivity.this, "Video has been saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(int videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                                Toast.makeText(VideoKycActivity.this, "Error saving video: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        
              showProgressBar to the user or show message
        }
        public void onFinish() {
             recordVideo();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you help me out how can i implement it in my code. I can't figure it out.

Comment: This will create the issue with executor try to fin anyother view as i have also stuck in to it

Comment: Can you share you code pls.